# Getting Firebase Current User Info

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I get the current user's information in my application without using a listener like `onStateChanged` ? Right now I'm using:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(function(user){ }
```

to get the user info then assign it to a variable .. but when I refresh the page, the variable loses its assigned value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a synchronous call by using `$firebaseAuth` service

```
$firebaseAuth().$getAuth();
```

It will return the currently signed-in user or `null` if no user is signed in.

Comment: good to hear it works for you,please accept it as answer so that others could gain help

Comment: i have a bit of a problem though , when i refresh the page it returns a null even though i haven't signed out just yet . hmm

Comment: it because after refresh, your $scope variable where you saving data, it get empty. so you should again call $getAuth() after refresh page.there Should be no problem if you are using Angular routing as your whole controller code(including your $getAuth line) will re-run .

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) using `currentUser` should do the trick:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Comment: yah but it needs a listener .. and that listener messes up other parts of my code